# Why was this question of mine closed?

Tags: discussion, support

[Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1591533/implications-of-making-a-software-source-available-instead-of-open-source) edited for clarifications.

I did not ask for a software license or license recommendation, I asked about the implications. I still haven't got the answer about why the two different close reasons in a span of two days.

---

Okay, my original question was closed; and, now this question in Meta, which is supposed to be a place for discussions, is also closed!

---

I posted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1591533/implications-of-making-a-software-source-available-instead-of-open-source) just now.

Two days ago, I had asked a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1590618/how-does-source-available-compare-to-open-source). It was closed with the reason that it was **opinion-based**. I got the idea that it was indeed opinion-based, but on-topic.

Today, I modified the question (wording), but it got closed, this time with the reason that it is **off-topic**. (The reason I posted this here is because the [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com) forum does not allow source-available questions.)

What is the actual reason for my questions being closed? If you have any re-wording suggestions, I would be glad to make the changes. I request that my question be re-opened.

---

Both questions got closed in under a minute. It would have made more sense to me if the community as a whole got to see the question and then boo'ed me. Please understand that not everybody is intricate with exactly what would be acceptable. But the way the questions are being closed, as if I knowingly posted something inappropriate, it only gives off a "you're not welcome here" vibe. I admit that the Moderators know better than I and I respect that, but I would rather come to a friendly environment and not somewhere where I would have to walk around on egg shells.

Again, if you have any re-word suggestions for making it on-topic, please let me know.

Comment: You are asking about problems with people and their opinions and interpretations, not anything to do with hardware or software.

Comment: I am asking for people's input regarding something related to computer software, based on their expertise and/or experience.

Comment: If you (or anybody) could re-word the question to fit it better, please do. If this belongs in some other forum, please migrate it. If anybody could give me some improvement pointers, to make it on-topic, please do.

But, please know that I am neither asking for license recommendations nor some opinions. I am trying to understand the effects of using one over the other, purely from a technical perspective.

Comment: @a_das - We are not a forum.  Questions seeking a discussion or our opinion about a topic are actually specifically out of scope.  The implications of "open source" vs "source available" is not a topic that is within scope here at Super User.  Since discussions are not allowed on any Stack Exchange community, your question as it's currently written, would also be out of scope on an appropriate SE community about software development.  (It would NOT be within scope at Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 1):

This is simply the wrong community to ask a question about software licensing.

See the Help Center section: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

> and it is not about …
>
> - programming and software development

---

That issue aside, I would like to point out some things to improve the question if you find the right community to post it on:

Open Source software is a specific kind of "source available" software where the terms of use meet certain criteria. You haven't provided any license or terms of use for either option (open source vs source available). There just isn't enough information to make the comparison between those two options, or to tell you how they will affect your users.

If there are *any* restrictions on the use of the source code, the following statement from your question would contradict that...

> as source-available, it would NOT impede, in any way, how an end-user uses it; plus, they would be free to modify it as per their needs.

So I would also replace this with the actual terms of use you intend to release the source code under so that there is no confusion.

Comment: I did not ask for a license recommendation; I asked about the implications of using source-available instead of open-source, whatever differences there are between those two.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Your question is still about software development, which is off-topic for the superuser community.